# How to fix code in Android to resolve "cannot find symbol"?

Tags: android

I don't fix the error. How should I edit code.

Try add:

```
package android.graphics;

import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode;
import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode.Mode;

public ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator(final IBitmapTextureAtlasSource pBitmapTextureAtlasSource, final IBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorShape pBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorShape, final int pColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt, final int pTolerance, final int pColorSwapColorARGBPackedInt, final TextureAtlasSourceDecoratorOptions pTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorOptions) {
        super(pBitmapTextureAtlasSource, pBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorShape, pTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorOptions);

    this.mColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt = pColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt;
    this.mTolerance = pTolerance;
    this.mColorSwapColorARGBPackedInt = pColorSwapColorARGBPackedInt;
    this.mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(pColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt, pTolerance, Mode.TARGET));
    this.mPaint.setColor(pColorSwapColorARGBPackedInt);

    if (SystemUtils.isAndroidVersionOrHigher(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)) {
        Debug.w("The class " + ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.class.getSimpleName() + " is deprecated for Android API Level: '" + Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN + "' and higher, since the class " + AvoidXfermode.class.getSimpleName() + " is deprecated since then.");
    }
}

@Override
public ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator deepCopy() {
    return new ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator(this.mBitmapTextureAtlasSource, this.mBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorShape, this.mColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt, this.mTolerance, this.mColorSwapColorARGBPackedInt, this.mTextureAtlasSourceDecoratorOptions);
}
```

Error:

> Task :andEngine:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New\Super\andEngine\src\main\java\org\andengine\opengl\texture\atlas\bitmap\source\decorator\ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
>   import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode;
>                          ^
>     symbol:   class AvoidXfermode
>     location: package android.graphics
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New\Super\andEngine\src\main\java\org\andengine\opengl\texture\atlas\bitmap\source\decorator\ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.java:11: error: package android.graphics.AvoidXfermode does not exist
>   import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode.Mode;
>                                        ^
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New\Super\andEngine\src\main\java\org\andengine\opengl\texture\atlas\bitmap\source\decorator\ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
>           this.mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(pColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt, pTolerance, Mode.TARGET));
>                                       ^
>     symbol:   class AvoidXfermode
>     location: class ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New\Super\andEngine\src\main\java\org\andengine\opengl\texture\atlas\bitmap\source\decorator\ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
>           this.mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(pColorKeyColorARGBPackedInt, pTolerance, Mode.TARGET));
>                                                                                              ^
>     symbol:   variable Mode
>     location: class ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New\Super Max World\andEngine\src\main\java\org\andengine\opengl\texture\atlas\bitmap\source\decorator\ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
>               Debug.w("The class " + ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.class.getSimpleName() + " is deprecated for Android API Level: '" + Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN + "' and higher, since the class " + AvoidXfermode.class.getSimpleName() + " is deprecated since then.");
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
>     symbol:   class AvoidXfermode
>     location: class ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   5 errors

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code, use Log for debug the code

```
   if (SystemUtils.isAndroidVersionOrHigher(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)) {
    Log.d("The class " + ColorSwapBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator.class.getSimpleName() + " is deprecated for Android API Level: '" + Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN + "' and higher, since the class " + AvoidXfermode.class.getSimpleName() + " is deprecated since then.");
}
```